# How is the register designed in a CPU

Tags: gdb, cpu-registers

I've known that there are some registers belonging to a process.

I've some basic questions about them:

When I use `gdb` to debug some project, I can see that the arguments of functions are pushed into some registers. So does each function have its own registers for its arguments? Or do all functions in the same process share the same registers for their arguments?

Does these registers are shared between threads? between processes? If not, when the CPU does a context switch, how do the values in the other registers are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to lack basic understanding or how CPUs work. Reading a computer architecture book, such as "[Computer Organization and Design: the Hardware/Software Interface](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0128122757)" by Patterson and Hennessy, or watching Ben Eater's "Build an 8-bit computer from scratch" [video series](https://eater.net/8bit) will likely help.

> I can see that the arguments of functions are pushed into some registers.

There are many different calling conventions. *Loading* arguments into specific registers (you can't *push* anything into a register), or *pushing* arguments onto a stack are common.

> So does each function have its own registers

No. A processor has a fixed set of registers. If a function uses e.g. `$RDI` for its first argument (the `x86_64`calling convention) and wants to call some other function, then it may need to temporarily save the value of `$RDI` in memory before overwriting it in order to pass argument to the other function.

> Or do all functions in the same process share the same registers for their arguments?

All functions in all processes share the same set of CPU registers (regardless of what the registers are used for).

> Does these registers are shared between threads?

The registers are shared, but each thread has its own *values* of registers. The OS (or in some cases the threading library) saves and restores the values when switching between threads.

> between processes?

Same as with threads.

> If not, when the CPU does a context switch, how do the values in the other registers are stored?

The CPU doesn't do a context switch (CPUs have no concept of context), the OS does, by storing the current set of values to one location in memory and loading a different set from another location.